# NHibernate: ошибка при сохранении объекта в БД

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Суть такова: я получаю объект типа *A* запросом через `session.CreateSQLQuery(query)`, после чего я создаю новый объект типа *B*, в котором ссылаюсь на мой свежеизвлеченный объект *А* и сохраняю.

Впоследствии, при вызове `session.Flush()` я получаю ошибку со ссылкой на объект типа *А*

> NHibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or
>   set cascade action for the property to something that would make it
>   autosave.

Почему так происходит? Я же только что достал его из БД, почему NHibernate считает его совершенно новым? Установка `Cascade.SaveOrUpdate` не вариант

Comment: А сессия одна и та же или новую создали? Если создали новую, то сущность А лучше приаттачить явно.

Comment: @Monk Все происходит в одной сессии.

Comment: enSO вроде рекомендует настроить зависимости правильно, чтобы сохранялось автоматом - https://stackoverflow.com/q/20027493/3768545

Comment: @Monk, спасибо за ответ, но, как я указал в вопросе, это решение мне не подходит, я не использую каскадное сохранение по иным причинам. Вообще, меня интересует даже не столько решение моей проблемы, а стремление понять, почему так происходит, ибо подобное поведение мне кажется удивительным.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос тогда маппинг ваших A и B. Потому как если есть ссылка, наверное есть и какое то указание на неё в маппинге. У хибера есть разные варианты маппинга вроде для разных ситуаций, я пока не уверен, как это у вас. ПС: я у себя логично наделал референсов и всяких hasmany и вроде картина сошлась и хибер работает.

Comment: Причин может быть очень много. Без маппингов не понять.